# Use Custom SSL in docker application

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have followed the steps given to run the kiwi tcms with docker. I can successfully setup the process.
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html

But, im not sure how to use my own certificate files on this website.

I have used my custom domain "testportal.mycompany.com" in the initial setup of docker-compose. I have a certificate file of "*.mycompany.com" domain. I just want to apply it now.

How to apply the custom certificate to the site, where can I find the location to replace certificate files.

Comment: The doc you linked already contain

"If you want to use different SSL certificate you need to update the localhost.key and localhost.crt files located under /Kiwi/ssl/ or bind-mount your own SSL directory to /Kiwi/ssl inside the docker container"

Comment: @Martheen: I don't see any folder/files located in that name. Could you please tell the full path where can I find the folder. I have used root user to setup docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

So you put your SSL files alongside your docker-compose.yml file and then mount them inside the app docker container. For example see:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L7

This is mounting the local file `./99-charset.sh` under `/usr/share/container-scripts/mysql/init/99-charset.sh` inside the db container.

So you will mount your own certificate files under `/Kiwi/ssl/localhost.key` and `/Kiwi/ssl/localhost.crt`

Update:
if you are new to docker you may want to engage your sysadmin/devops counterpart to help you out. Assuming you are aiming to deploy Kiwi TCMS into production this isn't something you will do yourself if you don't have any experience in the subject.

Comment: Thanks, Actually yes im new to docker, but the experienced developer in IIS hosting, I can do it myself, pls share under what category I should mount my certificates. I mean the local file ./99-charset.sh line placed under "services: -> db: -> volumes: ". What structure should I follow to mount certificate.